# how to store the data of multiple numbers of fields of form?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form in which user can increase or add numbers of fields as he wants.

the fields are adding successfully.....

for this I use javascript and  the code is here..

```
<script type="application/javascript">
var counter3 = 0;
function addAuthor() {
    // Get the main Div in which all the other divs will be added
    var mainContainer = document.getElementById('Author');

    // Create a new div for holding text and button input elements
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');

    // Create a new text input
    var newText = document.createElement('input');
    newText.type = "text";
    //var i = 1;
    newText.name = "Author[]";
    //newText.value = counter3 + 2 + ". ";

    //Counter starts from 2 since we already have one item
    //newText.class = "input.text";
    // Create a new button input
    var newDelButton = document.createElement('input');
    newDelButton.type = "button";
    newDelButton.value = "-";

    // Append new text input to the newDiv
    newDiv.appendChild(newText);
    // Append new button input to the newDiv
    newDiv.appendChild(newDelButton);
    // Append newDiv input to the mainContainer div
    mainContainer.appendChild(newDiv);
    counter3++;
    //i++;

    // Add a handler to button for deleting the newDiv from the mainContainer
    newDelButton.onclick = function() {
        mainContainer.removeChild(newDiv);
        counter3--;
    }
}
</script>
```

and I have a form here..

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type = "text" name="Author[]" />
    <input type="button" value="+" id="Authorbutton" onclick="addAuthor()" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

I use php and mysql queries to save the data into database..
and the code code is..

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$authors = $_POST['Author'];
foreach($authors as $author) 
{
    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (number, type) VALUES ('{$_POST['type']}','{$author}')");

    if (!$sql){
       die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
//endforeach;

}
}

?>
```

but the problem is that the data does not store properly in database...

it saves only the first field in the database but not for 2nd, 3rd, 4th and so on...

help me ........

Comment: Personally, i wouldn't iterate over the fields this way. You may want to build one SQL statement then run that. But PLEASE, make sure you sanitize your input, you are leaving yourself WIDE open to SQL injection.

Comment: Okay nevermind, I see you are inserting multiple rows.

Comment: What do you mean it only saves the first 'field'? Do you mean field as in 'Author' or do you mean it only saves the first row?

Comment: @BarryChapman : it means it saves only first row... in first row I have only one field...

Comment: Where is `type` submitted with the form? You're PHP assumes it is set (and is very insecure).

Comment: Don't give the submit button a name or id of "submit", as it will mask the form's submit method (i.e. `form.submit` will reference the button, not the method).

Comment: What's the contents of $_POST?

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (number, type) VALUES ('$_POST['type']','$author')");
```

and in your view file it should be

```
 <input type = "text" name="Author" />
```

Comment: this also store only the first field and not other

Comment: Sorry i didnt see it is $_POST['type']; are you getting it now..??

Answer (score 0):

Just will suggest to do a `print_r($_REQUEST)` and check out what all you getting as data in the request. 
Plus will also like you to check in firebug / chrome inspect tools to check if you adding the elements correctly to the browser or not. Because looking at the code, it dont seems to be running correctly. 
The very one thing missing in here is the ID - Auther, and you getting the element by id which itself fails.
Plus, also tried running the same with that fix / patch, but was not able to run through to check the output.
So will like you to check in as what is the exact value you getting in the requests. If the form submit is going to pass only single data back to the the server, that will always be trouble for you to get the response / desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$authors = $_POST['Author'];
$valuesToInsert =   1;
for($i=0;$i<count($authors);$i++) 
{   $number = $i +1;
    $valuesToInsert .=   "($number,$authors[$i]),";

}
$valuesToInsert =   trim($valuesToInsert,',');
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (number, type) VALUES ".$valuesToInsert);    
    if (!$sql){
       die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
//endforeach;

}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to submit 2 separate arrays with the same names. When an author is added each time, you will get

```
$_POST['Author'][1] = 'foo';
```

instead of

```
$_POST['Author'][1] = 'foo';
$_POST['Author'][2] = 'bar';
```

which is what you are expecting. You should try to make the inputs already have indexes, i.e.

```
<input type = "text" name="Author[1]" />
<input type = "text" name="Author[2]" />
```

etc. You can incrementally increase the input indexes with your counter3 JS variable, and do something like

```
newText.name = "Author[" + counter3 + "]";
```